# How do you setup a wireless network on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, networking

I have a couple of desktop computers running windows xp that are set up on a wireless network what I am trying to do though is set it up to where if I log on to any computer I have my settings on that computer.  All the tutorials I am searching just tell me how to set up the network I have it set up I just want to add users where they can log on to any computer and have their settings show up. Any suggestions of tutorials that cover this for Windows xp?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for has nothing to do with wireless. It is called setting up an [Active Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory) domain with [roaming profiles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738596%28WS.10%29.aspx). To do this you need a Windows Server 2000/2003/2008/2008R2 machine to act as the [Domain Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_controller), so unless you want to spend the $$ on that, you can't do what you are asking for in a home environment.

Comment: @waterfallrain - No problem. If you are satisfied that this answers your question, you can click the check mark under the voting to the left of my answer.